# Django Rest Framework ListAPIView - many if-s in get_queryset()

Tags: python, django

Please review my DRF ListAPIView code. There are a lot of `if` statements. I wonder if it's a good approach to put these `if-s` in `get_queryset()`. How can I improve this?

```
class ReportList(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ReportSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ]

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Report.objects.all()

        # search filters
        status = self.request.query_params.get('status', None)
        count = self.request.query_params.get('count', None)
        candidate_name = self.request.query_params.get('candidate_name', None)

        if status:
            qs = qs.filter(status=status)
        if candidate_name:
            qs = qs.filter(user__name__icontains=candidate_name)
        if count:
            qs = qs[:5]    

        # per user role objects permission
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_company_admin:
            return qs.filter(
                user__company=user.company).exclude(status=constants.DRAFT)
        elif user.is_recruiter:
            return qs.filter(
                user__company=user.company).exclude(status=constants.DRAFT)
        elif user.is_approver:
            return qs.filter(
                user__approver=user).exclude(status=constants.DRAFT)

        # if user is requester:
        return qs.filter(user=user, user__company=user.company)
```

Comment: IMO it is a correct solution. The first block with 3 `if`-conditions should stay there. The block with `if`-`elif` can be eventually changed slightly by outsourcing some of the operations. You could implement `ModelManager` for excluding the DRAFT reports. That would make your code DRY.